# Caused by: javax.media.opengl.GLException: Not a GL3 implementation

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I am getting a "Not a GL3 implementation exception" in the method init when it tries to do the assignment.

```
void init(GLAutoDrawable glad){
GL3 gl3 = glad.getGL().getGL3();

}
```

I downloaded the jogamp-all-platforms. I am using Eclispe IDE and configured the build path by making a new user library. The new user library has all the jars of the jogamp-all-platforms in it. I looked at similar questions but it is not that helpful.

Comment: Could it be that your hardware does not support OpenGL3? Or that you have multiple graphiccards where only one supports it?

Comment: @BDL Don't know. I tried to find out but,some say the integrated graphic card(Intel 3000) I am using can be used with OpenGL3, but when I change GL3 to GL2 it doesn't error. Makes me think it can't be used. But maybe I am not looking at something correctly

Comment: @Rika have you updated your GPU drivers?

Comment: @Rika: Have you checked out the [first answer in this post](http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?;topic=21064.0)?

Comment: @BDL I am not able to look at that link yet, I have to wait until I get home

Comment: @PeterT No I didn't update any drivers, I 'll perhaps do that when i get home

Answer (score 0):

You should read [this document](http://jogamp.org/jogl/doc/Overview-OpenGL-Evolution-And-JOGL.html). In your case, glad.getGL() is probably a GL4bc instance or a GL2 instance. It depends on the GLProfile instance you use in your code.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I've found to debug these kinds of things is to get a GLProfile and print it as a string -- this way, you can easily see whether or not your system actually supports a specific version. You can do this with something like:

```
GLProfile glp = GLProfile.get(GLProfile.GL3);
final GLCapabilitiesImmutable glcaps = (GLCapabilitiesImmutable) new GLCapabilities(glp);
final GLCapabilities tGLCapabilities = new GLCapabilities(glp);

System.out.println("System Capabilities:" + glcaps.toString());
System.out.println("Profile Details: " + glp.toString());
System.out.println("Is GL3 Supported?: " + glp.isGL3());
```

Comment: Thanks it looks like the computer I am on does not support GL3